# How to remember rows selected and maintain them after reload by default in UITableView?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios4

How can I set a row selected by default? I want to select a row , take the number of selected row with `indexpath.row` and then reload the table and select the row what was selected. Can someone help me please? Can I get the selected row in a method -(`IBAction`) `segmentedControlIndexChanged`? Not in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`?

This is my code if it can help you to understand

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    //lbl1 = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, 100, 20) ];

    // Configure the cell...
    NSString *depdateChoosed=[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:depSelectedIndice];
    NSString *comeateChoosed=[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:comSelectedIndice];
    NSString *choosedDate =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",depdateChoosed, comeateChoosed];
    NSLog(@"date choisi %@ ",choosedDate);

    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text =[deparatureDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {
         //cell.textLabel.text =[goingBackDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.textLabel.text=[goingBackDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text =[goingBackDates objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@" champ séléctionner : %d ",indexPath.row);

    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        depSelectedIndice=indexPath.row;  
    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {
        comSelectedIndice=indexPath.row;
    }
    //[tableView reloadData];
}

-(IBAction) segmentedControlIndexChanged
{
    int i;
    switch (self.segment.selectedSegmentIndex) 
    {
        case 0:
            i=0;

            [tableView reloadData];
            break;
        case 1:
            i=1;
            NSLog(@"dexieme segment selectionner");
            [tableView reloadData];
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

will give you the `NSIndexPath` for the current selected row.  You can then do

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                       animated:NO 
                 scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle];
```

to select that row (and show it in the middle of the screen) later.

Comment: method NSIndexPath indexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]; can't return int ?

Comment: Also, make sure you have `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` on your `UITableViewController` set to `NO`, otherwise it will automatically deselect the row when the view appears. This was bugging me for hours.

Comment: After I call this in `viewDidAppear` this works on iOS 8

Answer (score 31):

I had the same question, and this is how I did it:

In your `tableViewController`, add this in this function

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView: (UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
    if(indexPath.row == 'the row you want to select')
    {
        [tableView 
            selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
            animated:TRUE 
            scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone
        ];

        [[tableView delegate] 
            tableView:tableView 
            didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
        ];

    }

}
```

Comment: Yep, selecting a cell this way, when it is being handled to the tableView, ensures it will be selected even if you call [reloadData]. This seems to work better than implementing it in [viewWillAppear].

Thank you!

Comment: This is the only solution if your table view appears animated. Don't select default cells in viewDidLoad / viewDidAppear!

Comment: @refdev I'm not sure this method will work if the table is very big, as then not all cells might be crated at once (only the first 50 or so) and the others later on demand. If your row is below that initial limit, the code within the `if` is never executed unless the user scrolls down.

Answer (score 9):

This will do it:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:section];
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Where **row** is the cell number you want to select (starts 0...), and **section** is the section where the cell appears.

Comment: I had a `UITableView` with +130 rows and this worked for me. I call it in the `viewWillAppear`. +1 thanks

Answer (score 5):

This is how you preselect a row in a UITableView:

```
[tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
```

Set the indexPath to be the row you want selected and then make the method call as above.

Comment: thank you but i can't use int ? tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:3 ?

Comment: you CAN NOT use an integer.  you MUST pass in an indexPath, as shown in many answers here. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 4):

I realize that this question is rather old (2011), but just to also post an up-to-date answer, in case someone (like me) searches for this problem and stumbles across this question:

With iOS 9, Apple has improved `UITableView` a lot. To make sure that focus is not lost when a table is reloaded, just do this:

```
tableView.remembersLastFocusedIndexPath = Yes;
```

and it will "magically work".

Even better, implement

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForPreferredFocusedViewInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
```

in the `UITableViewDelegate` to let the table know which row you want selected when it is drawn to screen for the very first time.

Before iOS 9, I'd usually just write my own `reloadData` method, that gets the currently selected row, reloads the table and then selects it again. Either in the `UITableViewController` or if I needed that to work with a table where I couldn't prevent code calling `reloadData` directly, I subclassed UITableView and overrode `reloadData` (hey, delegation is the preferred way, but sometimes you just have to subclass and override, even in iOS).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to get the selected rows in a table view. :)

```
NSArray *selectedRows=[tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
        NSMutableArray *rownumberArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i=0; i<selectedRows.count; i++) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [selectedRows objectAtIndex:i];
            NSInteger row = indexPath.row;
            NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:row];
            [rownumberArray addObject:number];
        }
```

//  rownumberArray contains the row numbers of selected cells.

Comment: You could simplify this a bit using `for (NSIndexPath *ip in selectedRows) [rowNumberArray addObject: @(ip.row)];`