# how to pre-select a row in a UItableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to set row selected by default in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118071/how-to-set-row-selected-by-default-in-uitableview)

Hello,
i use this method to get the selected row

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@" champ séléctionner : %d ",indexPath.row);

    if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==0)
    {
        depSelectedIndice=indexPath.row;

    }
    else if(segment.selectedSegmentIndex==1) {


        comSelectedIndice=indexPath.row;
        }
```

can i , when i reload the table, select a row from the number depSelectedIndice or comSelectedIndice ?
thank you

Answer (score 2):

You could try [selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html). To pass in an IndexPath you can use:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:depSelectedIndice inSection:0]
```

or

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:comSelectedIndice inSection:0]
```

So all together you do:

```
[yourTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:depSelectedIndice inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone]
```

Comment: That worked for me, but I found I also had to send tableView:didSelectRowForIndexPath: to have it act accordingly.