# How to select row in uitableview programmatically based on NSString

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a uitableview that hosts a number of cells, in another part of the app the user will make an NSString selection that will match on of the cells in the uitableview, how can I select hat cell programmatically?

I tried using the method

```
 selectRowAtIndexPath:animated
```

but how can I get the indexpath? is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118071/how-to-set-row-selected-by-default-in-uitableview

Comment: i hope you would have an array from which you are populating your tableview, search in your array and get that index, then use that index to get that row using selectRowAtIndexpath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are loading data from an array. Then just search inside that **NSArray** and take index of the matched object. Now you can create **NSIndexPath** programatically:

```
[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:section];
```

Just use this **NSIndexPath** to select the row

Answer (score 0):

The way you needs to get the `indexpath` from source array is

```
int selectionIndex;
if([sourceArray containsObject:userSelectionString])
{
  selectionIndex = [sourceArray indexOfObject:userSelectionString];
}
```

You have to check whether selection object is there or not before get the indexpath from sourceArray.then you have to use this `indexpath` for `selectRowAtIndexpath:animated` method

Answer (score 0):

try this .... first try to get the cell number based on string

```
NSString * pUserSelectedString = @"abcd";
int index;
if([array containsObject:pUserSelectedString])
{
      index = [array indexOfObject:pUserSelectedString];
}
```